# custom google search api color filter for android

Tags: android, api, search

I am using google custom search api to search images, which is working fine. Now, I want to add some filter to the search result i.e. display images of a specific color, size,  type, file type. I tried using following parameters but it did not work:

```
&imgc=color&imgcolor=color_yellow&imgSize=icon
```

Comment: Searching for "filter google image search" will bring you here: https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search